# Flutter, the chat scroll is activated late when opening the keyboard

Tags: flutter, scroll, keyboard, chat, delay

I'm building a chat app with Flutter.
I've implemented a chat scroll that start when the user open the keyboard. The scroll move the last message of the conversation above the keyboard when it's open.

The problem is that the scroll start with a delay. It start after the keyboard is completely open and for 1 second the keyobard overlap the chat messages.
I want to move the chat simultaneously with the keyboard opening.

That's the code:

```
chat.page (the main component)

class ChatPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const ChatPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const ConnectivityWrapper(
      child: ChatPageWidget(),
    );
  }
}


class ChatPageWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const ChatPageWidget({super.key});

  @override
  State<ChatPageWidget> createState() => _ChatPageWidgetState();
}

class _ChatPageWidgetState extends State<ChatPageWidget> {
  final ScrollController scrollController = ScrollController();
  late final KeyboardLifecycleEventHandler keyboardLifecycleEventHandler;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    //Listen to keyboard state changes to push up messages
    keyboardLifecycleEventHandler = KeyboardLifecycleEventHandler(
      onKeyboardVisibilityChanged: (bool keyboardVisible) {
        if (keyboardVisible) {
          // Schedule scrollToFitKeyboard to run after the next frame
          WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
            scrollToFitKeyboard(keyboardVisible);
          });

        }
      },
    );
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(keyboardLifecycleEventHandler);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(keyboardLifecycleEventHandler);
    super.dispose();
  }

  void scrollToFitKeyboard(bool keyboardVisible) {
    final double keyboardHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom;

   try {
      if (scrollController.hasClients && mounted) {
        scrollController.animateTo(
          scrollController.offset +
              (keyboardVisible ? keyboardHeight : -keyboardHeight),
          duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 10),
          curve: Curves.easeInOut,
        );
      }
    } catch (e) {
      debugPrint(e.toString());
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    final String languageCode = Localizations.localeOf(context).languageCode;
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: SharedPreferences.getInstance(),
      builder: (BuildContext buildContext,
          AsyncSnapshot<SharedPreferences> snapshot) {
          context.read<ChatCubit>().getCredits();

        return BlocBuilder<ThemeCubit, ThemeState>(
          builder: (context, themeState) {
            return BlocBuilder<GeolocationCubit, GeolocationState>(
              builder: (geoLocContext, geolocationState) {
                final location = geolocationState.city;
                return BlocBuilder<ChatCubit, ChatState>(
                  builder: (context, chatState) {
                    //GET CHAT SESSION DATE
                    final formattedDate =
                        formatDate(chatState.messages, languageCode);

                    return GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        FocusScope.of(buildContext).unfocus();
                      },
                      child: ConstrainedBox(
                        constraints: const BoxConstraints.expand(),
                        child: Scaffold(
                          backgroundColor:
                              themeState.themeSchema.bg().defaultColor,
                          resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,

                          //Appbar
                          appBar: AppbarWidget(
                            themeState: themeState,
                            location: location,
                            onTap: () {
                              Navigator.of(buildContext).push(
                                MaterialPageRoute(
                                  builder: (buildContext) =>
                                      const SettingsPage(),
                                ),
                              );
                            },
                            context: buildContext,
                          ),

                          //Body
                          body: Stack(
                            children: [
                              SafeArea(
                                child: Column(
                                  children: [
                                    //Chat body
                                    Expanded(
                                      child: ChatBody(
                                        context: context,
                                        themeState: themeState,
                                        location: location,
                                        scrollController: scrollController,
                                        date: formattedDate,
                                        loading: chatState.loadingBubble,
                                        messages: chatState.messages.isNotEmpty
                                            ? [
                                          VestaMessage(
                                              text: LocaleKeys.onboardingTwoChatOne.tr()),
                                          ...chatState.messages
                                        ]
                                            : [
                                          VestaMessage(
                                              text: LocaleKeys.onboardingTwoChatOne.tr()),
                                          ...chatState.messages
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    //Chat input bar
                                    ActionBar(
                                      themeState: themeState,
                                      scrollController: scrollController,
                                      loading: chatState.loadingBubble,
                                      credits: chatState.credits,
                                      location: location,
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                              Positioned(
                                bottom: 0,
                                left: 0,
                                right: 0,
                                child: SizedBox(
                                  width: double.infinity,
                                  child: ActionBar(
                                    themeState: themeState,
                                    scrollController: scrollController,
                                    loading: chatState.loadingBubble,
                                    credits: chatState.credits,
                                    location: location,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),

                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                );
              },
            );
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

```
keyboard-life-cyle-handler file

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class KeyboardLifecycleEventHandler extends WidgetsBindingObserver {
  final Function(bool) onKeyboardVisibilityChanged;

  KeyboardLifecycleEventHandler({required this.onKeyboardVisibilityChanged});

  @override
  void didChangeMetrics() {
    final bool keyboardVisible = WidgetsBinding.instance.window.viewInsets.bottom > 0;
    onKeyboardVisibilityChanged(keyboardVisible);
  }
}
```

I've tried changing the duration property but it's not the solution.
I've tried replacing  `scrollController.animateTo` with `scrollController.jumpTo` and it didn't worked.

Thank you so much!

Comment: For the the screen to start scrolling, your content must be greater then the length of your screen otherwise your content will fit into the screen and it won't scroll.

Comment: The scroll start when WidgetsBinding.instance.window.viewInsets.bottom > 0;
In my case the scroll start but with a delay.